# Add individual cells to a drop down list (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-2016

If I want to add a set of cells to a drop down list in Excel, that is no issue with the highlight feature:
[image]

[image]

However, let's say I want the list to contain only A, C, and E.

When I hold down the Ctrl key to select the individual cells (B2, B4 and B6), I get an error message saying I can't use reference operators on data validation criteria. How do I add the cells then without typing everything manually?
[image]

Comment: That's default behaviour of the data validation